# How to do " or \r in Prism.js in Angular6

Tags: angular6, prismjs

So I'm trying to have Prism highlight the following Arduino code snippet on my site.

```
client.print(String(\'\'GET \'\') + url + \'\' HTTP/1.1\r\n\'\' +
               \'\'Host: \'\' + host + \'\'\r\n\'\' + 
               \'\'Connection: close\r\n\r\n\'\');
```

I initially had to change all of the `"` to `''` but now it interprets `\r\n` as a line break and displays it as such. Any thoughts?

Comment: Note I use a double quote initally, then two single quotes to make it look like double quotes.

Comment: Please note: `''!="`

Comment: Yeah, I know It's just for my personal site and is only meant to show some of my home projects. I add a link to my github for the actual code. If your aware of a way to do " in Prism then I'd be glad to use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, actually just got it. Use `\'\'\\r\'\'` to express what will be interpreted as `"\r"`.

Comment: I've formatted the strings as code so that the backslashes are rendered properly. I'm assuming that you want double backslashes in `\\r`.

Comment: Thanks for the syntax fix Nisse! That is what I meant to express.

Comment: By the way, did you mean `''\r''` rather than `"\r"`?

Comment: Well preferably I'd like to use double quotes " but I've had issues with it in prism (the two single quotes were my workaround). If you're aware of a way to do that that would be even better!

Comment: I meant in your answer. `\'\' ` should translate to `''`, not `"`.

Comment: Oh yes your correct there, I just use the two single quotes to make it look like double quotes because I hadn't found a way to do it otherwise.